# Multiple elements in one database cell

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

The question is how database design should I apply for this situation:

**main table:**

```
ID | name | number_of_parameters | parameters
```

**parameters table:**

```
parameter | parameter | parameter
```

Number of elements in parameters table does not change. `number_of_parameters` cell defines how many `parameters` tables should be stored in next cell.

I have problems to move from object thinking to database design. So when we talk about object one row has as much parameters as `number_of_parameters` says.

I hope that description of requirements is clear. What is the correct way to design such database. If someone can provide some SQL statments to obtain it it would be nice. But the main goal of this question is to understand how to make such architecture.

I want to use SQLite to create this database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relational way is to have two tables. The main table has an ID, name and as many other universally-present parameters as possible. The parameters table contains a mapping from an ID in the main table to a parameter name and a parameter value; the main table ID should be a foreign key, and the combination of ID and name should be unique.

The number of parameters can be found by just counting the number of rows with a particular ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you can serialize the data whiile saving to the database and deserialize it back when you get the record it will work. You can get total number of objects in serialized container and save the count to the `number_of_parameters` field and serialized data in `parameters` field.

Comment: You mean using it as blob data? It's not nice thing cause database will be only usable and editable in my application. There will not be possibility to edit it in other SQLite tools.

Comment: Nope, if you can serialize the data in JSON format yuou can save it to the VARCHAR field.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one perfect correct way, but if you want to use a relational database, you preferably have relational tables.

If you have a key-value database, you place your serialized data as a document attached to your key.

If you want a hybrid solution, both human editable and single table, you can serialize your data to a human-readable format such as yaml, which sees heavy usage in configuration sections of open source projects.