# Filtering sqlite - performing actions one by one

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, cgi

I'm working on a Python program that interacts with a simple sqlite database. I'm trying to build a search tool that will be able to, depending on user input, interactively "filter" the database and then return rows (items) that match the search. For example...

My Python program (through if statements, cgi.FieldStorage(), and whatnot) should be able to accept user input and then hunt through the database. Here's the general code for the program:

```
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import sys
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('bikes.db')
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
terrain_get = form.getlist("terrain")
terrains = ",".join(terrain_get)

handlebar_get = form.getlist("handlebar")
handlebars = ",".join(handlebar_get)

kickstand = form['kickstand'].value
```

As you can see, that part is what receives the user's input; works fine (I think). Next, where I need help:

```
if 'dirtrocky' not in terrains:
    FILTER the database to not return items that have "dirtrocky' in their terrain field
```

And then later in the program, I want to be able to extend on my filter:

```
if 'drop' not in handlebars:
    FILTER the database to, much like in previous one, not return items that have 'drop' in their 'handlebar' field
```

My question is, HOW can I filter the database? My end result should ideally be a tuple of IDs for rows that are left after I 'filter away' the above.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show database schema you have in mind? How do you want to store multi-valued fields like terrain?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I assume I would just be using multiple tables. However, in looking at the answers at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535685/multiple-elements-in-one-database-cell), etc., I'm a bit unclear as to how one would set that up. I understand the idea of a *main table*, which includes ID, title, price, etc. However, for multi-valued fields, how do you set that up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should define your database schema. Most common approach is to create fully normalized database, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE bikes (
    bike_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    manufacturer VARCHAR(20),
    price   FLOAT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE terrains (
    terrain_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    terrain VARCHAR(20),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE handlebars (
    handlebar_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    handlebar VARCHAR(20),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE bike_terrain (
    bike_id INTEGER,
    terrain_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE bike_handlebar (
    bike_id INTEGER,
    handlebar_id INTEGER
);
```

Note that `bikes` table does not contain anything about terrain types or handlebars: this info will be stored in connecting tables like `bike_terrain`.

This fully normalized database makes it little bit cumbersome to populate, but on the other hand, it makes it much easier to query.

How do you query it for multi-valued fields?

You will need to construct your SQL statement dynamically, something like this:

```
SELECT
    b.manufacturer,
    b.price
FROM bikes b,
     terrains t,
     bike_terrain bt
WHERE b.bike_id    = bt.bike_id
  AND t.terrain_id = bt.terrain_id      
  AND t.terrain IN ('mountain', 'dirt', ...) -- this will be built dynamically
  ... -- add more for handlebars, etc...
```

Almost whole WHERE clause will have to be built and added dynamically, by constructing your SQL statement on the fly.

I highly recommend getting some good SQLite GUI to work on this. On Windows, SQLite Expert Personal is superb, and on Linux `sqliteman` is great.

Once you get your database populated and it has something beyond few 100s of rows, you should add proper indexes so it works fast. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I'll go to sleep now and hopefully wake up fully revived and ready to work some magic. Or, you know, programming. No real difference. I'll look in `sqliteman` as well.

Comment: I've started inputting the database. I'm a bit curious though as to how I can add user-inputted data to the SQL statement. Is there a way to "break it apart" so that I can insert various variables? Or do I have to just do it by combining a variety of variables/strings and then just sending them all as one big query in the end (i.e. a = "AND"; b = a + selector, etc., etc.)

Comment: This is what I typically do - carefully construct SQL statement. Be careful to sanitize your data used to create such SQL or use prepared statements with `?` to avoid SQL injection. In python or perl you can build dynamic array of parameters for prepared statement to achieve that